# Перестал работать XMLHttpRequest

Tags: xmlhttprequest, javascript

доброго времени суток.
пишу для программы веб интерфейс и столкнулся со странной проблемой, перестал работать XMLHttpRequest. Вечером все работало стабильно, утром увы ... 
Программа работает нормально, на запросы отправленные через строку браузера реагирует

```
    function start(outputElem) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

            xhr.open('GET', ''+
            '?<?xml version="1.0"?>'+
            '<methodCall>  <methodName>Start</methodName></methodCall>', true);

            xhr.send(null); 
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Второй параметр `XMLHttpRequest.open` должен быть URL, а не данные. Данные передаются в `XMLHttpRequest.send`.